# Help with armatures

Tags: armature, bones

I'm trying to rig a gate to be able to open, but I'm not sure how. I want to be able to rotate the top bar then have the others follow naturally with gravity. How would I do this?
[image: Gate model]
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but let's try:

- Create your bones. Only bone 4 is parented to bone 1.
- Give bones 2 & 3 a *Copy Rotation* constraint with bone 1 as *Target*.
- Give bone 4 a *Track To* constraint with bone 3 as *Target*, *Head/Tail* > 1, *Space > Pose Space <-> Pose Space*.

When you rotate bone 1 the other ones should follow.

[image]